# Does any GTA game feature another GTA title as a mini game?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-series

Are there any mini games inside any of the Grand Theft Auto games that is essentially a mini version of an older GTA title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't think so. There were mini games in san andreas (arcade, betting etc) and in gta4 (pool, bowling, darts) but none of them actually allowed you to play GTA inside GTA :)

Comment: I'm looking forward to the hidden copy of PGR 1 I expect to find in Geometry Wars Retro Evolved 3.

Answer (score 7):

GTA and GTA2 are available as free downloads if you just want to play them!

http://www.rockstargames.com/classics/

Answer (score 1):

There are however IIRC sections you can get to in GTA: San Andreas that take you to hidden maps from earlier games.

Comment: where? how to get there?